# Unable to install Windows via Boot Camp - Unable to Partition

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition

I am unable to proceed beyond the initial screens of Boot Camp in order to install Windows 10.  I am told the:

`The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition.`

Upon checking I only have a single partition, my OS X partition, as per the screenshot below.

If I dismiss that prompt there is no way to proceed with an installation.  So, how do I install Windows 10?

[image]

Output of: `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 19457/255/63 [312581808 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  312581807] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

And output of `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  311909984      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  312319624     262151         
  312581775         32         Sec GPT table
  312581807          1         Sec GPT header
```

Macbook model is: `MacbookPro5,5`

Comment: I used to have a Recovery HD, had the same issue.  Most of the recommendations on the internet say to get rid of Recovery HD, so I did.  Same thing with that too.

Comment: OK the last MB/MBPs (originally) shipped with 160 GB disks are from the year 2009. The newest Windows possible is Windows 7 and you can't install Win10 on them. Please add your Mac model.

Comment: I'm happy to install Windows 7 instead.  Model is MacbookPro5,5 - just added to question

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've solved it by now, but I had exactly the same problem with fresh new Macbook pro 2017 and I had to reinstall the system (MacOS). Then the installation of Windows 10 through bootcamp went fine.